# (node:14000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So i'm trying to make a command where it generates codes that might be the winning code number, and I want the codes to keep on repeating/sending and each person must copy 1 number. But I keep getting this error and it doesnt send a message:

```
(node:14000) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

lottery.js =

Here is the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'lottery',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const lottery = require('../text.js');
        setInterval(() => {
            const item = lottery[Math.floor(Math.random() * lottery.length)];
            message.channel.send(item);
        }, 5 * 1000);
    }
}
```

text.js =

```
`w2H1
DmKS
wSLS
yRpQ
8J57
0qlq
hRRc
Cn8G
B0FL
D2H0
k3dD
jchM
MWyN
VK5m
NllW
CKxJ
0mKq
b4rR
Bl5t
dDdt
5MT0
84s1
7DwG
mzDW
06rl
R3Hl
fG82
tnbt
lc02
6TDh
MySv
FgBq
3g30
qB6B
QQyq
wQMr
nMg5
PvK9
jL72
zZ8z`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `text.js` has a lot of line breaks, so `item === '\n'` sometimes since `item` is
a random character from `lottery`. When you do `message.channel.send('\n')`, Discord throws a "Cannot send an empty message" error because it counts a whitespace-only message as empty.

I think you intended for `item` to be an entire *line* of `lottery` instead of just a character, so you can change your code to:

```js
const text = require('../text.js');
const lottery = text.split('\n');
const item = lottery[Math.floor(Math.random() * lottery.length)];
\\ ...
```

Comment: Now i'm getting a new error: TypeError: require(...).split is not a function. I did what you told me too, but I don't completely know what to do.

Comment: @Outrage edit your file manually so it's like `module.exports = \`w2H1\nDmKS\nwSLS etc...\``

Comment: It just starts sending random letters not words. Is there a fix to that?

Comment: by letters I mean 1 digits from the whole thing

Comment: `lottery` should be an *array* of strings, not just a string. I've updated my answer, assuming `text.js` uses `module.exports = `